# Unable to block all subdomains of spammy urls

Tags: .htaccess

My site is getting spammed by lots of different blogspot urls (such as `http://somespammyurl.blogspot.com.br`), but I can't figure out how to block them, I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?.blogspot.co.id.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?.blogspot.bg.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?.blogspot.ru.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?.blogspot.com.*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http(s)?://(www\.)?.blogspot.com.br.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

but in my raw logs I still see spammy urls with http/1.0/ 200, which I'm assuming means they are getting through, because if I specify the exact whole url of one of the spamming urls in the htaccess, the raw log line says http/1.0" 500 for that url. Can anyone shed some light why those lines aren't blocking all *.blogspot.co.id for example?

Is there a way to simply block all:

*.blogspot.*

because I'm getting blogspot.pt, blogspot.eu and all sorts.

Comment: "My site is getting spammed by lots of different blogspot url" --- what does it mean? And what your rewrite rules are supposed to do?

Comment: my site is getting hammered by blogspot urls hotlinking files and crippling my sites (2 minutes to load), my hosting said they need to be blocked to relieve stress on the server.

Comment: "hotlinking files" --- your rules should be fine then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block all **.*blogspot** referers, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?.+blogspot [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Your existing rules dont match the referer string **http://www.blogspot** because of the extra dot infront of **.blogspot** in your cond pattern.

Comment: I tried that but still getting through. I'm trying to block: http://somespammyname.blogspot.com and different variations of the subdomain name and the extension, is your code definitely for that?